# Content Assist doesn't work in xml with support library

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, content-assist

I had to use Navigation Drawer from the support library v4 in my Android app.

I linked the library with my project in eclipse. Copied it to the libs folder in my Project.
Library classes are accessible to me in my java file. Imports work fine. Even the xml code that i copied from [**this**](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android) website works fine. I didn't change any resource ids.

The main problem is the content assist in eclipse.Its messed up when i use the DrawerLayout tag as the top parent tag.

When i try to press ctrl + space inside any block nothing will pop up.

When i change the values of attributes the output of the app changes. But the content assist just wont work.

It shows up properties like Layout_height and layout_width when i press ctrl +  space inside

**android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout** tag but will not show any result inside other tags

It all happens because of DrawerLayout tag being placed at the top.
If i dont use it as the parent tag, everything works fine.

Please Help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was doing the same thing from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) website and was bounded in the same problem.

You must **understand** that you need to define those color resources **yourself** in the strings.xml file. Define your own color combination. While I understand that the tutorial must have described this but I think you are the one who can select the colors liked to you, the best.

Define the colors in strings.xml by using this tag :

```
<color name="name-of-color">hex-code-here</color>
```

Access the resource using : `@color/name-of-color` in your `xml layout` files.